# How can I find the dynamic xpath for the word "Pace" in the attached?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I need the dynamic xpath for the the word "Pace" in the below code  It is the the name of the third column in a table.

I have tried the following:

```
//table[contains(@class,'data-grid-table data-grid-fixed-row-table')]//span[contains(@class,'lightning-table-cell-measure-header-value')][contains(text(),'Pace')]
```

but this seems to be too long of a locator for my test.  Is there a shorter dynamic xpath locator that I can use? Here is the snippet of the code that contains the word:

```xml
<th data-row-index="0" data-column-index="0" data-fixed-row="true" data-fixed-column="false" aria-selected="false" aria-hidden="false" id="data-grid-24-fixedrow0-col0" class="data-grid-table-cell data-grid-table-cell-start data-grid-header-cell" tabindex="0">
   <div class="data-grid-table-cell-box" style="height: 17px;">
      <div class="wave-table-cell-measure-header">
         <span class="wave-table-cell-measure-header-text" data-tooltip="Pace" data-tooltip-on-truncation="true">
            <span class="lightning-table-cell-measure-header-value" tabindex="-1">
               <span class="header-icon-container">
                  <span class="slds-icon_container">
                     <svg aria-hidden="true" class="header-icon-sprite slds-icon">
                        <use xlink:href="/images/sprite.analytics.svg#formula"></use>
                     </svg>
                     <span class="slds-assistive-text">
                        Formula
                     </span>
                  </span>
               </span>
               Pace  
            </span>
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="data-grid-resize-slider" style="position: absolute; width: 0px; height: 0px;">
   <input class="data-grid-resize-slider-input" aria-label="Pace Column Width: 115" type="range" tabindex="-1" min="35" max="1000" value="115">
</div>
</th>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue may be with the double `[][]` notation you are using for your `//span` element at the end. I've never seen that type of XPath syntax before, and I've always grouped queries into a single set of `[]`.

You can use the following XPath:

```
//th/div/div//span[contains(text(), 'Pace']
```

This will get you the `span` element containing text 'Pace'.

If you just want to fix your existing XPath syntax, this might work too:

```
//table[contains(@class,'data-grid-table data-grid-fixed-row-table')]//span[contains(text(),'Pace') and contains(@class,'lightning-table-cell-measure-header-value')]
```

I've combined your last two queries into one using `and` operator.